# Bash executing the result of a command

Tags: bash

I've got a small script which is returning a string/path. This path is an executable, how can I run the executable? Thank you.

Example:
my_command commands `other commands` ... returns /home/mydesktop/myexecutable
I'd need to execute /home/mydesktop/myexecutable

Comment: An 'executable' is more of a permission than an atomic object the way an .exe sort of is in Windows. What program actually runs the executable? You just need to call its command-line arguments appropriately in your script most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
`your_command args etc`
```

The backticks get replaced by the output of the command and that is then evaluated. Since it is at the start of the input line, `bash` tries to execute it.

This is a handy trick to know, since you can use it for all sorts of fun:

```
cp your_file .backup/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`_your_file
```

will prepend the current date to a copy of your file for poor mans backup...

**EDIT**: In the comments, we learned, that you should actually be using the `$()` syntax. So, that amounts to:

```
$(your_command args etc)
```

and

```
cp your_file .backup/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")_your_file
```

since you can nest this...

Comment: What if I'm already using substitution in the command? How to use it two times? I have: mycommand args... `other command with substitution args` Thanks.

Comment: @user1523953: This is the main reason you should use `$()` instead. You can nest `$()` as much as you want: `$(echo $(do some command to $(the result of some command)))`

Comment: wow. this is good to know. maybe i should have read modern books, instead of learning unix from and old book by pike ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it returns an executable script/program use:

```
chmod +x /home/mydesktop/myexecutable
/home/mydesktop/myexecutable
```

If it returns an executable STRING use:

```
eval STRING
```